# What's the fourth Star Trek movie?

Tags: star-trek

I'm a new Star Trek fan and I want to watch all the television series and the movies, but I don't know in what order the movies go. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Trivial search for 'Star Trek Movies' returns Star Trek (film franchise) Wiki providing user everything they need.  No research at all on their part.  And per Beofett's comment, does appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: I agree a trivial search revealed the answer, but I don't think it's a duplicate; it was very specific. What's the *fourth* Star Trek movie, not what order do I watch the show and movies. And admittedly it can be confusing since they dropped the numbers after VI, but part 4 was called Star Trek IV : The Voyage Home. This person did not try at all.

Comment: @Meat Trademark The body of the question also asked 'what order the movies go', that's what led me to the duplicate.  It provides them with additional info beyond chronological order.

Comment: The body of the question did not ask that question. Even your quote is out of context.  The "what order the movies go" is prefaced by "I don't know" which lends credence for his REAL question. What's the 4th movie? Not generic, not a list. They just wanted to know "The Voyage Home" was the 4th movie. I don't understand why this is considered the standard "recommended viewing order" question since it was so specific.

Comment: @MeatTrademark 'but I don't know in what order the movies go'.  How is that out of context ?  And I stand by the duplicate.  Questioner says they're new to the series and they want to watch ALL the television series and movies.  Perhaps those of us that voted to mark as duplicate felt there's an implied question in the body beyond that explicitly stated in the question title.  The question/answer we've pointed the QP seems to answer that implicit question well.

Comment: Why, it's Star Trek IV obviously.

Answer (score 2):

The Motion Picture (1979)

The Wrath of Khan (1982)

The Search for Spock (1984)

The Voyage Home (1986)

The Final Frontier (1989)

The Undiscovered Country (1991)

Generations (1994)

First Contact (1996)

Insurrection (1998)

Nemesis (2002)

Star Trek (2009)

Into Darkness (2013)

Comment: I almost added those 2, but since the user was only asking for the fourth movie the list already felt like overkill without bringing up the reboot.